# CCD Sensor parallel implementation of Smear

Tags: compute-shader, photo-realistic

I have rendered an image with 32bit float color channels and want to simulate the smear effect of a CCD sensor (see figure 1).

[image]

**Figure 1:** Image of a light source. Here the full-well capacities of the pixels are oversaturated. Therefore, the charge has jumped to neighboring pixels. Since the vertical pixels of a CCD sensor are connected to each other, the charge flow is vertical. Whenever a pixel is fully saturated, the overcharge iteratively jumps to neighboring pixels.

In principle, each pixel is a bucket and each photon is a drop of water. When the bucket is full, the water flows into the neighboring bucket until it is also full and so on... The smear ends as soon as the excess overload has been accommodated in neighboring buckets. This is why this effect ends directly without fading.

I am looking for an algorithm that can calculate the saturation shift of a column in parallel. The problem is that the rendered image does not look like the image in the example. The rendered image has a natural environment with a light source that is larger than one pixel. This means that the buckets are partially filled from the start and not only one pixel is over saturated.

**What I did already:**

I've been thinking a lot about how to quickly check if a column of pixels is fully saturated:
Each pixel within the column can perform an atomicAdd operation on an SSBO variable. With this information, we can easily check whether the entire column is fully saturated:

```
bool columnIsFullySaturated = atomicCounter >= countPixelInColumn * fullWellCapacity
```

If `columnIsFullySaturated` is true, we can simply set all pixels to 100% saturated. If not, we need to do further checks. We can also add a second SSBO variable to store the number of pixels that are oversaturated. If this number is zero, we do not need to make any further changes for this column. If this number is greater than zero, we need a parallel algorithm to distribute the oversaturation to the neighboring cells.

I have an algorithm in mind where each pixel is calculated by a compute shader call. A workgroup is created for each column. It looks like this:

```
shared int32 saturation[columnSize]; // here the saturation is stored
shared bool isOversaturated = true; // some helper variable to check for a termination

//load values to shared memory
saturation[gl_localInvocationID.y] = texture(tex, coord).r;

atomicAdd(atomicCounter , saturation[gl_localInvocationID.y]);

barrier();    

bool columnIsFullySaturated = atomicCounter >= countPixelInColumn * fullWellCapacity

if(columnIsFullySaturated) // set all to 100% saturated
{
    saturation[gl_localInvocationID.y] = fullWellCapacity;
    return;
}
if(atomicCounterHasOverSaturation == 0) // keep it as it is
{
    return; 
}

//this is the else part (we need to manage the over saturation)

do
{
    //check both neighbors and exchange over load to the lower saturation neighbor. By atomicAdd operation
    isOversaturated = false;
    barrier();
    isOversaturated |= saturation[gl_localInvocationID.y] > fullWellCapacity;
    barrier();
}while(isOversaturated);
```

With this algorithm, I have the problem that when the column is almost completely oversaturated, the cells shift the overcharge backwards and forwards... and that takes too long.
I hope there is an algorithm that does this more analytically than just shifting each charge.